# re-organizing array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have an array of objects that contain information for different activities in different projects.
It looks something like this

```js
const input = [
  {
    Project: 1,
    ID: "1-1",
  },
  {
    Project: 1,
    ID: "1-2",
  },
  {
    Project: 2,
    ID: "2-1",
  },
];
```

From this, I would like to go to this

```js
output = [{
    Project: 1,
    ID1: 1 - 1,
    ID2: 1 - 2,
  },
  {
    Project: 1,
    ID1: 2 - 1,
  },
];
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
let currentProject = ''
let output = []


for (const e of input) {
  let counter
  let outputObj = {}

  if (currentProject !== e.Project) {
    output.push(outputObj)
    counter = 1
    outputObj = {}

    outputObj.projectNum = e.Project

    currentProject = e.Project
  }

  if (currentProject == e.Project) {
    outputObj['ID' + counter] = e.ID
    counter++
  }

}
```

here's what I'm getting back:

```js
output = [{
    Project: 1,
    ID1: 1 - 1
  },
  {
    Project: 1,
    ID1: 2 - 1
  }
]
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, tried several times to fix it.
Could someone please help me get over the edge?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `ID1` and `ID2`, why not an array of IDs?

Comment: You're creating a new `outputObj` each time through the loop, not just when the project changes. Initialize it outside the loop.

Comment: Because these objects will be fed into a function one by one to carry out some other tasks.

Comment: This code actually does not produce the output you said you are getting back. Are you sure this is the routine you are using?

Comment: Yo can do this in two steps
1. Group `ID`s by `Project`
2. Convert the string to an expression

Comment: You're also re-initializing `counter` every time through the loop, so it won't actually count. It also needs to be initialized outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const input = [{
    Project: 1,
    ID: "1-1",
  },
  {
    Project: 1,
    ID: "1-2",
  },
  {
    Project: 2,
    ID: "2-1",
  },
];

const result = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { Project, ID } = curr;
  const obj = acc.find((el) => el.Project === Project);
  if (obj) {
    const length = Object.keys(obj).length;
    obj[`ID${length}`] = ID;
  } else {
    acc.push({ Project, [`ID${1}`]: ID });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way - `O(n)` *time complexity*

- Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to aggregate data.
- Using [`logical nullish assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) only assigns if `acc[Project]` is [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish) (`null or undefined`).
- Define each additional  key-value pair like:

```
const number = Object.keys(acc[Project]).length; // Define key format by number of existing property.
const key = `ID${number}`;
```

instead of using `count` variable.

```js
const input=[{Project:1,ID:"1-1",},{Project:1,ID:"1-2",},{Project:2,ID:"2-1",}];

const output = input.reduce((acc, {Project, ID}) => 
{
  acc[Project] ??= {Project}; // Get exist object or create new one

  const number = Object.keys(acc[Project]).length; // Define key format by number of existing property.
  const key = `ID${number}`;
  acc[Project][key] = ID;
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(output));
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "Project": 1,
    "ID1": "1-1",
    "ID2": "1-2"
  },
  {
    "Project": 2,
    "ID1": "2-1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^! @profiter

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
const input=[{Project:1,ID:"1-1",},{Project:1,ID:"1-2",},{Project:2,ID:"2-1"}];

let temp = {}; 
input.map(v=>(temp[v.Project] ??= []).push(v.ID));
let output = Object.keys(temp).map(k=>{
    let json = {Project:k};
    temp[k].map((v,k)=>json['ID'+(Number(k+1))]=v);
    return json;
});
console.log(output);
```

you will get the result.

```
[
    { Project: '1', ID1: '1-1', ID2: '1-2' },
    { Project: '2', ID1: '2-1' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you **intended** to implement this assumes every project from same id comes sequentially grouped.

While @decpk answer deals with with a linear search, for performance reasons I would rather first use a dictionary and then convert to an array, AND also keep track of id quantities using a field `n`.

```js
const input = [
    {
        Project: 1,
        ID: "1-1",
    },
    {
        Project: 1,
        ID: "1-2",
    },
    {
        Project: 2,
        ID: "2-1",
    },
];

const projects = {}

for (const e of input) {
    let pid = e.Project
    let project = projects[pid]
    //First time seeing this project
    if (!project) {
        projects[pid] = { Project: pid, n: 1, ID1: e.ID }
    }
    //insert more ID
    else {
        project.n += 1
        project[`ID${project.n}`] = e.ID
    }
}

//And now converting the object to array, removing the 'n' field
const output = Object.keys(projects).map(pid => {
    const obj = projects[pid]
    delete obj.n
    obj.Project = pid
    return obj
})
```